# Fixed layout or center homepage -SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, master-page, page-layout

I would like to have a homepage in SharePoint online to have a fixed layout ideally have it centered with equal spaces on the left and right.

Right now after removing the quick launch everything else shifts to the left.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Page Layout, you can modify blank web part page layout and keep only center panels

```
<%@ Page language="C#"   Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingLayoutPage,Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing,Version=16.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePointWebControls" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Register Tagprefix="PublishingWebControls" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Register Tagprefix="PublishingNavigation" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceholderID="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
    <SharePointWebControls:CssRegistration name="<% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/Style Library/~language/Themable/Core Styles/pagelayouts15.css %>" runat="server"/>
    <PublishingWebControls:EditModePanel runat="server">
        <!-- Styles for edit mode only-->
        <SharePointWebControls:CssRegistration name="<% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/Style Library/~language/Themable/Core Styles/editmode15.css %>"
            After="<% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/Style Library/~language/Themable/Core Styles/pagelayouts15.css %>" runat="server"/>
    </PublishingWebControls:EditModePanel>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server">
    <SharePointWebControls:ListProperty Property="Title" runat="server"/> - <SharePointWebControls:FieldValue FieldName="Title" runat="server"/>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server">
    <SharePointWebControls:FieldValue FieldName="Title" runat="server" />
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderTitleBreadcrumb" runat="server"> <SharePointWebControls:ListSiteMapPath runat="server" SiteMapProviders="CurrentNavigationSwitchableProvider" RenderCurrentNodeAsLink="false" PathSeparator="" CssClass="s4-breadcrumb" NodeStyle-CssClass="s4-breadcrumbNode" CurrentNodeStyle-CssClass="s4-breadcrumbCurrentNode" RootNodeStyle-CssClass="s4-breadcrumbRootNode" NodeImageOffsetX=0 NodeImageOffsetY=289 NodeImageWidth=16 NodeImageHeight=16 NodeImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/fgimg.png?rev=44" HideInteriorRootNodes="true" SkipLinkText="" /> </asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderPageDescription" runat="server">
    <SharePointWebControls:ProjectProperty Property="Description" runat="server"/>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderBodyRightMargin" runat="server">
    <div height=100% class="ms-pagemargin"><IMG SRC="/_layouts/images/blank.gif" width=10 height=1 alt=""></div>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
    <div class="ms-table ms-fullWidth">
                <div class="ms-table ms-fullWidth">
                    <div class="cell-margin">
                        <WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" Title="<%$Resources:cms,WebPartZoneTitle_TopLeft%>" ID="TopCenter"><ZoneTemplate></ZoneTemplate></WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="cell-margin">
                    <WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" Title="<%$Resources:cms,WebPartZoneTitle_Footer%>" ID="Footer"><ZoneTemplate></ZoneTemplate></WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
                </div>
            <SharePointWebControls:ScriptBlock runat="server">if(typeof(MSOLayout_MakeInvisibleIfEmpty) == &quot;function&quot;) {MSOLayout_MakeInvisibleIfEmpty();}</SharePointWebControls:ScriptBlock>
        </div>
</asp:Content>
```

OR

You can use CSS, to make the center aligned to your main DIV

```
#s4-bodyContainer {
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Virendra but I need the whole page centered with a fixed layout

Comment: whichever Main div is present in your page, you can apply css to make that div center aligned. Example: #s4-bodyContainer {
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
}

if you want to fix the size of body, you can add width property

Comment: Thanks Virendra I figured that out yesterday but how can I have the white area fill the whole screen below.Now I just get a rectangular size if there are no webparts on the page.